# Доработка кнопки

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Доработайте пожалуйста кнопку, в данный момент, использование Изображения для кнопки невозможно, изображение становится как на задний план.
Прошу исправить это

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_Project
{
    public class RoundButton : Control
    {
    public Color BackColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonBorderColor { get; set; }
    public int ButtonRoundRadius { get; set; }

    public Color ButtonHighlightColor { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonHighlightColor2 { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonHighlightForeColor { get; set; }

public Color ButtonPressedColor { get; set; }
public Color ButtonPressedColor2 { get; set; }
public Color ButtonPressedForeColor { get; set; }

private bool IsHighlighted;
private bool IsPressed;

public RoundButton()
{
    Size = new Size(100, 40);
    ButtonRoundRadius = 30;
    BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
    BackColor2 = Color.Silver;
    ButtonBorderColor = Color.Black;
    ButtonHighlightColor = Color.Orange;
    ButtonHighlightColor2 = Color.OrangeRed;
    ButtonHighlightForeColor = Color.Black;

    ButtonPressedColor = Color.Red;
    ButtonPressedColor2 = Color.Maroon;
    ButtonPressedForeColor = Color.White;
}

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
        createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        return createParams;
    }
}
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    var foreColor = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedForeColor : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightForeColor : ForeColor;
    var backColor = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedColor : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightColor : BackColor;
    var backColor2 = IsPressed ? ButtonPressedColor2 : IsHighlighted ? ButtonHighlightColor2 : BackColor2;


    using (var pen = new Pen(ButtonBorderColor, 1))
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, Path);

    using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, backColor, backColor2, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
        e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, Path);

    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(foreColor))
    {
        var sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
        var rect = ClientRectangle;
        rect.Inflate(-4, -4);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, rect, sf);
    }

    base.OnPaint(e);
}

protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
}

protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    IsHighlighted = true;
    Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
    Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    IsHighlighted = false;
    IsPressed = false;
    Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
    Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
    IsPressed = true;
    Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
    Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseUp(e);
    Parent.Invalidate(Bounds, false);
    Invalidate();
    IsPressed = false;
}

protected GraphicsPath Path
{
    get
    {
        var rect = ClientRectangle;
        rect.Inflate(-1, -1);
        return GetRoundedRectangle(rect, ButtonRoundRadius);
    }
}

public Brush Background { get; internal set; }

public static GraphicsPath GetRoundedRectangle(Rectangle rect, int d)
{
    var gp = new GraphicsPath();

    gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, d, d, 180, 90);
    gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y, d, d, 270, 90);
    gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 0, 90);
    gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 90, 90);
    gp.CloseFigure();

    return gp;
}
```

}

Comment: Не следует пересоздавать один и тот же вопрос.